# Efficient Way To Write Prime Number in Python

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

What is more efficient way to write prime number function in Python? Below is my version as I am learning Python:

```
def print_prime(max):
  i = 1
  while i < max:
    is_odd = True
    for nd in range(2, i):
        if nd < i and  i % nd == 0:
            is_odd = False
            break

if(is_odd):
        print(i)
    i += 1
print_prime(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I feel the optimised approach is the sieve of eratosthenes approach .The following blog educates about this and other approaches.
[Link here](https://www.javainterviewpoint.com/prime-number-program-in-python/)

```
def checkPrime(number):
numbersList = list(range(2,number+1)) 
for i in range(2,int(number**0.5)+1): 
    for j in range (i*i, number+1, i): 
        if j in numbersList: 
            numbersList.remove(j) 
return numbersList
number = int(input("Enter the range to check for prime ")) 
prime = checkPrime(number) 
print(f"******* Prime numbers between 1 to {number} **********") 
print(*prime)
```

Comment: A list of numbers is not very optimised, since both `list.__contains__` and `list.remove` is `O(n)`. The time performance can be improved by using either a list of booleans indexed by the number, or by using a set. (A list of numbers is more space-efficient though.)